# Loss function when the output is a single probability

Tags: regression, loss-function, pytorch

I have a regression problem where the output `y` is a single probability, i.e. real number that varies in the interval `[0, 1]`

While using L1 or L2 loss will very likely work well, I feel that they are not the most appropriate options considering that the range `[0, 1]` is already well defined.

Is Binary Cross Entropy ([BCE Loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) in pytorch) the most appropriate in this case?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing exactly, but you may have a look at beta regression https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/57686/71442

Comment: By L1 loss, do you mean "sum of the all the absolute differences between the true value and the predicted value" or lasso regression?

Answer (score 0):

At first I was going to say:

> It doesn't make sense to use use cross entropy loss in a regression
>   problem!
>
> See explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223256/tensorflow-cross-entropy-for-regression).

But then I realised that if you are really trying to do regression on *probabilities* it could have some sense.

But still, why would you use it instead of L1, L2? So maybe try it and let me know if it works better!

Comment: Well.. that is exactly what the question is about. :) Normally you would not use it, however, here it might be appropriate. I am looking for an explanation that is not based on experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting probabilities is can be framed as a beta regression.

That is a separate issue than adding a regularization term (i.e., L1 or L2).

Comment: I got the feeling that the OP mentioned L1 and L2 as MAE and MSE loss functions, not as regularization.